# Angular 8 @Input Child Component strange issue

Tags: angular, components, angular-components, angular8

**Introduction to my issues :**

1. I have Parent, Child Component.
2. Where clicking on Parent Table Cell (td) I am passing one value (positionLeft) to child component.
3. In parent component if the value is not satisfied then the Child Component (pop-up) should open on the left side.

**What is working :**

1. Able see the value in Child Component using ngOnChanges life cycle which has been passed from Parent.
2. Able to see the output in ChildTemplate.html template also.

*

> **What is not working :**
>   I have tried below three different attempts on **UL** but still no luck... :(

```
<ul [className]="positionLeft ? 'PositionToLeft' : '' "> 
    <li>India</li> 
    <li>England</li>
    <li>Australia</li>
    <li>{‌{positionLeft }}</li> // it's working , getting correct value 
</ul>
 <ul [ngClass]="{'PositionToLeft': positionLeft == true}"> 
    <li>India</li> 
    <li>England</li>
    <li>Australia</li>
    <li>{‌{positionLeft }}</li> // it's working , getting correct value
</ul> 
<ul [class]='positionLeft === true ? "PositionToLeft" : ""'> 
    <li>India</li> 
    <li>England</li>
    <li>Australia</li>
    <li>{‌{positionLeft }}</li> // it's working , getting correct value
</ul>
```

> I am not able to set the UL position to left using the above condition like *"positionLeft ? 'PositionToLeft' : '' "*

[image]

**Below is my actual code**

```
<ul class="EmployeeUpdateContainer" id="parent-list" *ngIf='isOpen'>
  <!-- onItemClickCatcher -->
  <li class="col-lg-12"  id="post-1" *ngFor='let it of Data' (click)="it.Name ==='Un-Roster' ? onSelectItem($event,it.Name,i) : return;">
    <span>{{it.Name}}</span>

    <!-- <ul *ngIf='positionLeft' [className]="positionLeft ? 'PositionToLeft' : '' " [ngClass]="{'PositionToLeft': positionLeft == true}" [class]='positionLeft === true ? "PositionToLeft" : ""' > -->
      <ul [class]="{'PositionToLeft': 'positionLeft' == true}">
      <li (click)='onSelectItem($event,it.Name,i)' [style.background]='i.Color' [class]='i.isSelected === true ? "spCla" : ""'
        *ngFor='let i of it.items'>
        {{i.Name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

<li class="col-lg-12">{{positionLeft}}</li>
</ul>
```

> Note: Passing the hard-coded class name to **UL** is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Try `[class.PositionToLeft]="positionLeft"`.

Comment: It's not working too the reason is getting class = 'undefined'

Comment: Hope you can provide a reproduction in https://stackblitz.com.

Comment: @HsuanLee Done,  Please check

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbka4t

Comment: `[style.background-color]="backgroundColor"`

Comment: Please see your example fixed https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onkrtm?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Yes even I was trying to replicate the issue but no success than I realize that the issue is because of something else please read the below comment for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Got the Solution

The issue I had called the same child twice in the parent component which in result passing two different values at same time.

I removed one and it start working.

Comment: Thanks every one for your valuable efforts.